# Method Getting Links from html Returning Duplicate Links

Tags: java, html, methods, hyperlink

I am building a web-crawler at one point I get the HTML from the start page and then hand it to another method which gets the links from it. I assuming I'm always using the same page so I'm only building it to work on that HTML. The problem is that the method is returning duplicate links and I can't figure out why. I checked the HTML that I'm pulling in and it is correct so the problem is with this method.
Here is the code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> linkParser(String htmlContents) {

        ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        int start = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        while (start < htmlContents.length() && !done) {

            int startIndex = htmlContents.indexOf("<A HREF", start);
            if (startIndex != -1) {
                startIndex += 9;
                String currentLink = "";
                int i = startIndex;

                while (htmlContents.charAt(i) != '"') {
                    currentLink += htmlContents.charAt(i);
                    start++;
                    i++;
                }

                links.add(currentLink);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return links;
    }
```

Here is the output when I call it:

```
[http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page1.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, page2.htm, foo://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/foo/default.htm, foo://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/foo/default.htm, http://www.foo.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/default.htm, http://www.foo.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/default.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/foo.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/foo.htm, http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/foo.htm, http://www.goduke.com/, http://www.goduke.com/, http://www.goduke.com/, http://www.goduke.com/, http://www.goduke.com/]
```

[Here is the page I'm using.](http://www.cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/default.htm) Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work

public static ArrayList linkParser(String htmlContents) {

ArrayList links = new ArrayList();
        int start = 0;

```
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        htmlContents = htmlContents.substring(start);
        int startIndex = htmlContents.indexOf("<A HREF");
        if (startIndex != -1) {
            startIndex += 9;
            String currentLink = "";
            while (htmlContents.charAt(startIndex) != '"') {
                currentLink += htmlContents.charAt(startIndex);
                startIndex++;
            }
            start = startIndex;
            links.add(currentLink);
        } else {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return links;
}
```